# Create UISegmentedControl with some segments working like buttons

Tags: swift, button, uisegmentedcontrol, selecteditem, selected

App with such behaviour:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cardi-mate-heart-rate-monitor/id1570842053

[image]

"W", "M" and "3M" work like an usual segment but when you click "Other" a screen appears and "pointer" jumps to the previously selected segment.

Tried to subclass `UISegmentedControl` and override `selectedSegmentIndex` but I can't even disable the selection of this item properly.

Could you please explain how to implement that?